# Tableau actions issue when using memberof() function

Tags: tableau-api

I have 2 charts of A and B in Tableau. Chart A filters chart B using an action.

My issue is when I use memberof() function in a calculation field in Chart A, the action stops working.

Can anybody help me with resolving this issue?

Comment: Please provide more detailed information regarding your specific issue, and what steps you have tried so far to try and resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The only Tableau function that I can find that might be applicable here is: ISMEMBEROF(see [User Functions](http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/functions_functions_user.html)). Depending on how you are employing that function in chart A, the lack of permission for the user may prevent a visual change in chart B.